# PHP function to get data from web service

Tags: php, web-services, json

How can I get data from [this web service](http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/Utils/Countries) using PHP?

I need a simple PHP function to list the countries.

#### Web service Data

```
{
   "valid":true,
   "id":"0",
   "data":{
      "@type":"genericObjectArray",
      "item":[
         {
            "id":"DE",
            "description":"Deutschland"
         },
         {
            "id":"ES",
            "description":"EspaÃ±a"
         },
         {
            "id":"FR",
            "description":"France"
         },
         {
            "id":"PT",
            "description":"Portugal"
         },
         {
            "id":"UK",
            "description":"United Kingdom"
         },
         {
            "id":"US",
            "description":"United States"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is on in `php.ini` (if not, use cURL library).

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/Utils/Countries ');

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$countries = array(); 

foreach($data['data']['item'] as $item) {
    $countries[] = $item['description'];
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/nZqAsofx).

Of course, handle if `$json` is `FALSE` (error with request).

Alternatively, if using >= PHP 5.3.

```
$countries = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['description'];
}, $data['data']['item']);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oLNglf).

Comment: Something is not right?! I'm getting wrong values on my array
print_r($countries);

Array ( [0] => g [1] => )

Comment: @Carlos You must be doing something wrong, because it definitely works.