# Reading XML from eternal URL with either PHP or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I'm really stuck and would appreciate any advice. I have an XML document I want to be able to read but I can't get it to work with either Jquery or PHP. I have read multiple pages on online and tried everything including JSON encoding. I have read nearly a hundred tutorials online but everything I do doesn't seem to work. Is anybody able to write a script that can enable me to use some of the nodes in my document? The code below is the best I have been able to do so far. Is anybody able to make it so I can loop through the nodes etc?

To the person who marked this as a duplicate I have tried to look at those questions but I can't access the URL. I therefore can't compare the nodes/etc to see what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate some help as I am quite new to this.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
  <?php
$url = "https://developerdemo.isams.cloud/api/batch/1.0/xml.ashx?
 apiKey=0A1C996B-8E74-4388-A3C4-8DA1E40ADA57";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$myJSON = json_encode($xml);
 ?>

<script>
var name='<?php echo $myJSON; ?>';
$.each(name, function(key, value) {
alert( "The key is '" + key + "' and the value is '" + value + "'" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591695/loading-file-with-simplexml-load-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to get data from web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087480/php-function-to-get-data-from-web-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the code you already have it's simply a case of working with the XML structure, the following example loads the XML and then gives a list of the pupils (with a few details)...

```
$url = "https://developerdemo.isams.cloud/api/batch/1.0/xml.ashx?apiKey=0A1C996B-8E74-4388-A3C4-8DA1E40ADA57";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ( $xml->PupilManager->CurrentPupils->Pupil as $pupil)   {
    echo $pupil['Id']." ".$pupil->SchoolCode." ".$pupil->Surname.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The id it puts out is the Id attribute of the Pupil element, the SchoolCode is the SchoolCode element in the Pupil.

The first few lines of output are...

```
1 101314800 Richards
3 PRE0000003SUF Thomas
5 PRE0000005SUF Davies
7 PRE0000007SUF Poole
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');    
$resultArray = file_get_contents('path/to/file.xml');
$resultArray = (array)simplexml_load_string($resultArray);
```

The result will be an array of XML Objects and arrays, which you can access later via their property name or index respectively ($resultArray["foo"]->foo).